# Event vb.net, how useful?

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, tcp

I've been searching for hour on how to create event with vb.net, but all tutorial seem pointless since they use event who already exist. Basically I don't get it.

So what I would like to raise a custom event so imagine a user connect it's detected here

```
Private Sub AcceptClient(ByVal iAr As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        Dim _listener As TcpListener = CType(iAr.AsyncState, TcpListener)
        Dim _client As TcpClient = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(iAr)

        'Here would be an event who's raised but I really don't know how'

        _client.GetStream.BeginRead(receiveByte, 0, 4096, AddressOf Receiving, _client)

        _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptClient), _listener)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return
    End Try
End Sub
```

So what would I like to do with the event don't really matter, but I don't know how to create my own event.

Also could someone explain the difference between calling a function where the comment is and raising an event.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this link it shows how to create and handle and event
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973905.aspx

Your question about raising an event vs calling a method 
[Raising events vs direct method calls differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660675/raising-events-vs-direct-method-calls-differences)